# Binding loop или два взимоисключающих ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

Есть два `ComboBox` источником данных которых являются два `ObservableCollection`.

Оба `ComboBox` привязаны к двум переменным в `ViewModel` в режиме `Mode=TwoWay`. Клас `ViewModel` реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Дилема в том что набор значений этих `ComboBox`'ов должен быть взаимоисключающим, то есть при выборе значения в первом - должен изменится набор значений во втором (наложиться определенный фильтр) и наоборот.

При вызове `ObservableCollection.Clear()` и заполнении его новыми данными соответственно многократно вызываются `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `INotifyCollectionChanged` что привод к переполнению стека (бесконечному циклу).

Собственно вопрос в том - как решить такую задачку?

Comment: Делайте только Remove элемента.

Comment: Ну, проблем быть не должно. На время применения фильтрации взведите булев флаг, который скажет, что на изменения, приходящие от фильтруемого комбобокса обращать внимание временно не нужно. По окончанию заполнения ObservableCollection сбросьте флаг.